# Difference between two implementation of comparator

Tags: c++, sorting, comparator

I have an object class named edge in my code, which requires the operator < to be defined for sorting objects. I defined it in two ways, while one works other just gives runtime error (segmentation fault). I want to know how this thing works? I am using std:: sort for my purpose.

```
struct edge{
    int u;
    int v;
    int w;

    edge(int a, int b, int c) : u(a), v(b), w(c){}

    bool operator<(const edge &other) const{
        return (w <= other.w);
    }
};
```

The above code gives runtime error.

```
struct edge{
    int u;
    int v;
    int w;

    edge(int a, int b, int c) : u(a), v(b), w(c){}

    bool operator<(const edge &other) const{
        return (w < other.w);
    }
};
```

The above code works fine.

Comment: Post a [mcve] please. The runtime error is probably caused in a specifi context you don't show here.

Comment: `std::sort` (because I assume that's what you mean), requires *strict-weak ordering*. Your first implementation doesn't satisfy that requirement.

Comment: A comparator is required to implement a strict weak ordering.   If it doesn't then, if used with standard library algorithms (like `std::sort()` and many others), the result is undefined behaviour.    Thanks to its use of `<=`, your first version does not implement a strict weak ordering.

Comment: Thanks @Peter
I didn't know it was undefined behaviour. I have been using it for so long giving no issues to me, today is the first time I saw this problem.

Comment: @molbdnilo what will go wrong if a<a is returned to be true, basically in compare(a, b) I want to implement which one to place before another, so if compare(a,a) returns true then I mean a should be placed before a, which should be no issue. Am I right?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ the above problem occured on a very specific test case available on an site called interviewbit, which is big enough to post here. The code was basically the implementation of Kruskal's algorithm.

Comment: @TarunGupta Try standing in front of yourself and see how that works out.

Comment: @TarunGupta _"which is big enough to post here"_ You probably meant the opposite. But anyways post a [mcve] or we won't accept that something specifically claimed happens with the code you posted, sorry.

Comment: @TarunGupta I guess that's fine if you already know to compare(a, b). But what about when you do compare(b, a)? And then compare(a, b) to see whether the two are equal? You're f##ked.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit yeah, I guess there is a problem. Thanks a lot for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're violating two requirements on a strict weak ordering:

- An object cannot be ordered before itself (`x < x` must be false), and
- If `a` is ordered before `b`, then `b` can't also be ordered before `a` (`a < b` implies `!(b < a)`).

Your violation of these requirements causes undefined behaviour.
(These are called *irreflexivity* and *assymmetry*.)

The third requirement is *transitivity*;

- If `a` is ordered before `b`, and `b` is ordered before `c`, then `a` is ordered before `c`.

These three are the "strict" part of "strict weak ordering".

The "weak" part is that, given `a` and `b`, one isn't necessarily ordered before the other (it's not a requirement that you must have either `a < b` or `b < a`).
Two elements `a` and `b` where neither is ordered before the other are *equivalent*.

Note that `std::sort`, like quicksort, isn't *stable*; equivalent but different elements don't necessarily end up in the same order in the result as they did in the input.

Comment: I was just curious why would sorting algorithm (similar to quicksort if I correctly assume) require a strict weak ordering, it should work otherwise also.

Comment: @TarunGupta Why do you think "it should work otherwise also"? If there is some code that expects a particular ordering and uses this in its algorithms, why should it be expected to work when a different ordering is given instead, particularly one that _isn't a less-than relation_?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit like if we see the algorithm of quicksort particularly
It chooses a pivot and then it just recursively partitions the array for which a strict ordering is not particularly required. Then, I guess, I am assuming it totally wrong.

Comment: @TarunGupta Maybe some algorithms exist for which your implementation is valid. However you forgot to tell us in your question what algorithm you're running, so we can only answer in broad strokes.

Comment: @TarunGupta Quicksort doesn't partition into `element <= pivot`  and `pivot <= element`. It keeps the equal elements on one side, which is why it's called a partition.

Answer (score 1):

`operator<` should return true if the first argument is **less than** the second and false otherwise. Sorting algorithms depend on this behaviour and may crash if it is not true.

Obviously the problem with

```
bool operator<(const edge &other) const{
    return (w <= other.w);
}
```

is that it returns true if the two edges are equal, which breaks the above rule, which means that sorting algorithms will not work.